# What does 'white' alone mean in cocktail recipes?

Tags: language, cocktails

I've come across the two following cocktail recipes:

> East Meets West
>
> Absolut Raspberry vodka, Cointreau, St-Germain
>   elderflower liqueur, pomegranate juice, lime juice, ***white***
>
> The English Writer
>
> Tanqueray gin, Aperol, pink grapefruit, acacia
>   honey, lime juice, ***white***

what does 'white' mean here? white rum? white wine? white liqueur (if there's such a thing)?

Comment: *Where* did you come across the recipes?

Comment: working on some translation.

Comment: What language is the source?

Comment: It's in English

Comment: What is the source of the recipes @Jawad? A book? the internet? We need more details.

Comment: A client. So, you've never seen 'white' mentioned alone?

Comment: That it is listed at the end implies it is a garnish. Angostura bitters (the classic) is in a white paper wrapped bottle...https://www.kegworks.com/angostura-aromatic-cocktail-bitters-16-oz-bottle?keyword=&matchtype=&device=c&adtype=pla&productgroup=183176240641&productidAG16&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzaqv64aI3AIVwrjACh0htQIPEAQYBSABEgIWyvD_BwE

Comment: problem is, when a certain cocktail contains Angostura, the name it explicitly

Comment: Can you contact the client to ask what is meant by "white"?

Comment: Where is your client @Jawad?

Comment: FWIW, my first thought was egg-white.  Are these shaken drinks?  (egg-white would give the shaken drink a foamy head/texture, but it being included as an ingredient in stirred drinks would indicate that is not the correct ingredient here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a couple of comments, this almost certainly means **egg white**, which is used in some shaken drinks to create a stable foam on top of the finished cocktail. It can also "round out" the flavor of a drink and prevent them from seeming overly sweet or tart. Neither of these is explicitly identified as a shaken cocktail, but that's the usual technique for drinks that include both sugar and citrus, as both of these do.

Some recipes use as much as an entire egg white, but much smaller quantities can be used if you crack and separate eggs before service, storing the whites chilled in a squeeze bottle, or mixed directly into a syrup you're making in bulk for one specific drink, a technique sometimes used to speed up service in high-volume bars. (For the "English Writer", you'd combine and keep chilled the non-alcoholic ingredients: grapefruit, lime, honey, and egg white. This allows your bartender to measure only 3 ingredients when making the drink rather than 6, which speeds the process and increases consistency.)

The abbreviation to simply "white" could mean any number of things: it could be they're using an egg substitute instead, or don't want to raise health concerns about the egg (which are minimal, but guests occasionally get squeamish) or the recipe simply got cut off (bartenders tend to list recipes from largest quantity to smallest). Without the exact context, it's difficult to say why the "egg" was left off here, but it wouldn't surprise me to see egg along with the other ingredients in both of these drink recipes. It's commonly used in cocktails and I can't imagine what else they might mean.

Comment: It would be quite an easy translation error, if it started in a recipe where the word for egg white is a single word (e.g. German *Eiweiß*) and the translator didn't realise that both words were needed in English.

Answer (score 1):

First - the recipe for East Meets West seems very off to me.  I mean it's not recipe for East Meets West. 
 Second - it's more close to Pomegranate Elderflower Vodka Drink.

- 1 1/2 vodka
- 1/2 elderflower liqueur such as St. Germain
- 1 pomegranate juice
- 1/2 fresh lime juice
- 1/4 simple syrup

AAAAAAnd because simple syrup is made from WHITE sugar I would say that this what they meant.

Also I've search for that second one because I've never heard of a drink with that name and only close in recipe was Gypsy Wedding.
Again - If the white means simple syrup this recipe is very strange because you already use honey (also all recipes call for honey syrup not honey in it's stale form).

for extra point I will point out that those recipes are very label oriented. Even Absolut on their drinks page don't mention other alcohols by name. 
Why Cointreau? Just triple-sec.

Comment: Well, these are 'Signature Cocktails' for some hotel in the Persian Gulf, hence the novelty names of the cocktails and the naming of certain brands.

Comment: Given that it always follows lime juice, could it mean *egg* white? http://mentalfloss.com/article/53127/why-do-bartenders-use-egg-whites-cocktails

Comment: It could be. Aperol is usually served as "fizz" where the prosecco take the role of fizziness.

Answer (score -5):

‘White’ in cocktail speak means with half n half, i.e. White Russian

Comment: In the *name* of the cocktail, perhaps, but nowhere will you find the recipe for a White Russian listed as "vodka, kahlua, and white".

Comment: Half-and-half in such a recipe would curdle instantly.